# Thread is not creating in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating thread in my onCreate method. I receive data via udp on the thread. For some reason it does not work.

```
private void UdpThread() {
//   server will listen to one client
    try
    {
        Thread udpServerThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {       
                Log.i("rrr","receivePacket3");
                try
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        sleep(1000);
                    Log.i("rrr","receivePacket2");
                    String[] recieved = null;

                    DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
                    InetAddress IPAddress = null;
                    try {

                        IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1500];
                    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                    try {
                        clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(8086);
                        Log.i("rrr","receivePacket");
                        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

                        Log.i("rrr","receivePacket1");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                    System.out.println("in client receive:" + modifiedSentence);

                    Log.i("Received data",modifiedSentence);
                    clientSocket.close();

                    modifiedSentence =  modifiedSentence.trim();
                    Log.i("Received data",modifiedSentence);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("UDP", "S: Error", e);
                }
            }
        };
        udpServerThread.start();
        //udpServerThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

        Toast.makeText(this,modifiedSentence,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("eeeee",""+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

how should i do when control not return immediately from thread.and wait until the data is not received.

Comment: What do you mean *"the thread is not creating and control jump to the toast"*? `udpServerThread.start();` will start the thread and return immediately, while the started threads runs in parallel, and your code will continue its execution to the next line.

Comment: Question is incomplete (I just fixed the language, spelling and formatting), you need to also share the Log.

Comment: @assylias then why i am not getting data via udp which i have coded in the thread.

Comment: @assylias what should i do for not return immediately.

Comment: @Rcp Don't you see the message corresponding to `Log.i("rrr","receivePacket3");`?

Comment: @assylias no i am not getting any log message if control enter the thread it prints Log.i("rrr","receivePacket3"); but i havent seen any log.

Answer (score 0):

to work with main thread from a second thread we have to use handler in android...
ex.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
            try{
                Message myMessage = new Message();
                myMessage.obj = "SEND ANY DATA";
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }).start();
```

and in handler.....

```
 private Handler finishHandler1 = new Handler() {
        @Override 
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // do the UI things..

        }
    };
```

Comment: what exception? can u show ur code and logcat for exceptions.. and instead of this                                             Log.e("UDP", "S: Error", e);                                            write             Log.e("UDP", "S: Error"+e);

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and init a Handler object and do it in the MAIN or UI thread. After that you will be able to post messages and Runnables to handler from the worker thread.

Alternatively, you can use

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
View.post(Runnable)
View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
```

You may Android [multithreading guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) very useful as well.